# Given any ODE is there a way to know if it has any explicit solution?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given any ODE of the form $$F(x,y,y',...,y^n)=0$$ is there a way to know if there are any explicit solutions?

For example for the differential equation

$$(1+y^2)(e^{2x}-e^yy')-(1+y)y'=0$$ the solution I can come up with is
$$\dfrac{e^{2x}}{2}+C=\arctan(y)+\dfrac{ln|1+y^2|}{2}+e^y+K$$

And I cannot find any explicit form of $y$ for that equation. (Don't know if there are)

So I am trying to generalize the case to any ODE, is there a way I can know if an equation has an explicit solution before even doing it?

Comment: Rudely speaking, if the general solution is in terms of the same family of functions (algebraic, rational, exponential, logarithmic) then it should be feasible to write down the solution in its explicit form. However, if the solution is a mixture of family of functions, then the way to bring it into explicit form should require numerical analysis.

Comment: The best way is to use Wolfram-Alpha.

Comment: I just plugged your equation into Wolfram-Alpha and it noticed it was separable, which I guess is clear in retrospect. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2By%5E2%29%28e%5E%282x%29-%28e%5Ey%29%28y%27%29%29-%281%2By%29y%27%3D0

Comment: In any event, a special case of your general structure is the ODE $y'-g(x)=0$ which has solution $y=G(x) + c$ where $G'(x)=g(x)$, and your question boils down to wondering if there is an explicit form of the antiderivative of $g$. Or if we are given a differentiable function $H(y)$ with $h(y)=H’(y)$ we can form the ODE $h(y)y’ -1 = 0$ which has solution $H(y) = x + c$ and it boils down to wondering if there is an explicit inverse of $H$.

Comment: I think I had the same question when I studied this stuff, but today I'm wondering what exactly is meant by an explicit solution. If the ODE is sufficiently well behaved you get a _unique_ solution for a given initial condition, and then this _is_ the explicit(?) solution. Several "well known" functions are defined just this way.